# QT application hangs while rendering QWebElement on QImage

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QWebPage class to load a page in background in my QT application.
Whenever it emits "repaintReqest", I try to render the contents of main frame onto a painter (QImage)
using code like below:

```
QWebpage page;
QImage m_image

onRepaintRequest(){
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    QPainter painter(m_image);
    page.mainFrame()->documentElement().render(&painter)
}
```

My application randomly hangs at `render` function call sometimes.
I ensure that `m_image` is not accessed by any other thread..
What could be the reason for this behavior?

Edit:: If I call render on main frame while QWebPage is updating it internally, can that cause hang? This is something QT should handle internally.

Comment: Is this function executed in the main thread ?

Comment: @alexisdm yes...QWebpage and onRepaintrequest are on main thread..

Comment: I also tried creating QWebPage on main thread and passing its reference to object on another thread. I am then receiving repaint events on separate thread but same issue of "sometimes application hangs while render" is still there. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- why `page.mainFrame()->documentElement().render(&painter)` rather than `page.mainFrame()->render(&painter)` ?
- As said in the doc, use the `void QWebFrame::render ( QPainter * painter, const QRegion & clip )` form to avoid rendering endless loop.

Comment: I do not want to wait for loadFinished signal. I need to run javascript in background and when page changes dynamically, only repaintRequested signal is emitted.
So, I am updating my image buffer inside repaintRequest.

Comment: And using "page.mainFrame()->render(&painter)", mysterious random application hang is still there. :(

Comment: Mmm... How is "onRepaintRequest" triggered? Doing the render probably triggers a relayout of the page. Might that trigger your javascript which triggers the "onRepaintRequest" leading to a loop?

Comment: This is [repaintRequested](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html#repaintRequested) signal which triggers onRepaintRequest. Your comment MAKES SENSE but mentioned link to doc says I can call render on receiving repaintRequest signal.

Comment: Also, in present scenario, no dynamic modification of page happens. I am trying to load google.com and getting stuck while calling render.

Comment: The doc says to call render with the "region" parameter. Might be that rendering the whole page instead induce the loop.

Comment: you were right. App Hang was due to loopback. Calling render indeed causes repaintRequest, frameContentsSizeChanged etc events. Now, I do early exit from function to avoid loop and also remember the dirty rect passed to repaintRequest call and unite them all when finally doing rendering.

Comment: Currently I write the frame contents to a file (different file everytime render is called). I have observed if I call render too frequently, then application crashes. I think this may be related to garbage collector not able to free memory etc. I will find about it more although currently I have put a 1 sec timer and allow 'render' only at 1 sec intervals.